# Rails asset pipeline not automatically compiling with esbuild only on WSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-subsystem-for-linux, sprockets, esbuild

I have a rails 6 app using esbuild to bundle all my js files to `app/assets/build`. I have to manually run `rails assets:precompile` in order for the changes that are in `app/assets/build` to actually be loaded from sprockets. I'll make a change to a file, I can see that esbuild has bundled the changes in `app/assets/build` but refreshing the page does not reflect the changes, unless I stop the server, precompile assets and then start server again. This is on my windows laptop running WSL

I just tested the exact same app on my macbook and the changes are picked up by the asset pipeline without having to manually precompile assets.

Any ideas on what the issue with windows/WSL is on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You shouldn't need to precompile assets in development. Do you have the foreman gem and have added the line `js: yarn build --watch` to your `Procfile.dev` file ? Yarn will watch any change to your JS and recompile autmatically into builds. Also I am under Linux, though it should work with Windows.

Comment: the esbuild side of things seems to be working fine - I can see the changes reflected in the bundle once a change is made with the `esbuild` command running (through foreman). The problem appears to be with sprockets as it's not compiling the assets in the pipeline by itself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was a `public/assets` folder being present. Removing that made assets get served from `assets/builds`

Comment: this worked for me. thank you. saved me so much wasted effort.